# Replace characters on left and right side of single character

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have this string:

```
3+5+6+2^5+9+1+2+32^2+10^10
```

I want to replace all occurrences of numbers on the left and right side of the ^ including the ^ but not including where the numbers end, such as the + symbols, with this as an example:

- 2^5 should now become Pow(2,5)
- 32^2 should now become Pow(32,2)
- 10^10 should now become Pow(10,10)

I'm looking for some sort of Regex or string replace that will only replace numbers (which can be decimals) on the left and right side of the ^ symbol and that are part of a larger string. My brain is hurting trying to make this work exactly right.

Comment: You should actually parse that thing instead of throwing regular expressions at it.  It can't account for order of operations.

Comment: When you say parse, how do you mean? I am running my expression through a math parser, but that parser doesn't support ^

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Why is regex so evil? In this competitive world, objectiveness matters.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo: Did I _say_ that "regex is so evil?" No, I made no such claim. He's clearly trying to convert some mathematical expression to potentially executable code. He might as well do it right. Regular expressions are a tool, and he's using the wrong tool for the job. The next questions to come up are, "why isn't this regular expression grouping these correctly... I can match them separately." It's conceivable that the next thing he may parse is `1^1^1`. Look at the problem and _then_ decide what the right solution is...

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not saying something doesn't mean it is not implied. Maybe I'm wrong about what you said... maybe you are wrong about what the question asks... you didn't say "regex is evil"... question didn't say "run the expression". We are both assuming implied statements that may be false. Of course, I am not saying you can't try to figure out the greater meaning of the question... as I can try to figure out a greater meaning for your commentary.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Also, maybe you are right about `1^1^1`! I agree with you. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groups to replace

```
Regex.Replace("yourString",@"(\d+)\^(\d+)","Pow($1,$2)");
```

`(\d+)` and `(\d+)` are captured in two groups i.e. `Group1` and `Group 2`(not group 0 since it contain the whole match)

When you replace it,you can refer to these groups in replacement string using `$1` and `$2`

Comment: I'll give this a try right now, thanks for the very fast answer.

Comment: Do I need to escape the \ like so (compiler is complaining): Regex.Replace(v, "(\\d+)^(\\d+)", "Pow($1,$2)");

Comment: You need to place `@` before the string, or escape the '\' char.

Comment: Like this: `@"(\d+)\^(\d+)"` or this `"(\\d+)\^(\\d+)"`

Comment: Ok, this answer was first and works. The answer below by Miguel Angelo also works.

Comment: True Miguel, I was torn who to accept and wish I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just tested, and works here:

```
    var str = Regex.Replace("3+5+6+2^5+9+1+2+32^2+10^10",
        @"(\d+)\^(\d+)", "Pow($1,$2)");
```

If you need more control on the replacement:

```
var str = Regex.Replace("3+5+6+2^5+9+1+2+32^2+10^10",
    @"(\d+)\^(\d+)",
    m => string.Format("Pow({0},{1})", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value ));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this one as the @ on the string is nice and easy.